# Convert hashtable/dictionary/array format data into regular column based data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, hashtable

I am a beginner in R and I never processed these type of data before. I have the following two types of sample data sets (df1 and df2) that looks like the following:

```
df1 <- c("{\"\"Wednesday\"\":4,\"\"Monday\"\":5,\"\"Saturday\"\":4,\"\"Thursday\"\":4,\"\"Tuesday\"\":5,\"\"Friday\"\":1,\"\"Sunday\"\":5,\"\"Missing day\"\":2}",
                "{\"\"Wednesday\"\":6,\"\"Monday\"\":5,\"\"Saturday\"\":2,\"\"Thursday\"\":6,\"\"Tuesday\"\":0,\"\"Friday\"\":2,\"\"Sunday\"\":4,\"\"Missing day\"\":1}",
                "{\"\"Wednesday\"\":5,\"\"Monday\"\":5,\"\"Saturday\"\":3,\"\"Thursday\"\":8,\"\"Tuesday\"\":4,\"\"Friday\"\":3,\"\"Sunday\"\":6,\"\"Missing day\"\":4}",
                "{\"\"Wednesday\"\":3,\"\"Monday\"\":5,\"\"Saturday\"\":4,\"\"Thursday\"\":1,\"\"Tuesday\"\":5,\"\"Friday\"\":4,\"\"Sunday\"\":4,\"\"Missing day\"\":6}")

df2 <- c("[373,357,382,411,310,315,330,385,367,396,402,348,354,343,392,395,392,401,376,448,341,373,369,304,298,332,366,287,334,222]",
         "[319,347,284,313,300,292,228,322,291,275,278,289,323,342,272,242,295,347,290,343,337,309,268,251,256,266,346,260,232,160]",
         "[165,154,161,152,164,152,156,150,137,170,147,210,235,190,176,175,191,186,209,157,210,199,162,149,162,165,174,171,178,126]",
         "[253,274,240,258,264,231,296,233,230,252,210,233,233,295,235,229,270,275,278,297,255,253,250,252,299,305,310,308,263,141]")
```

Now, I need to convert df1 into **df1_final** and df2 into **df2_final**. Here is how the final data sets should look like:

```
df1_final <- data.frame("Day"=c("Wednesday","Monday", "Saturday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Missing day"),
                "Count1"=c(4,5,4,4,5,1,5,2),
                "Count2"=c(6,5,2,6,0,2,4,1),
                "Count3"=c(5,5,3,8,4,3,6,4),
                "Count4"=c(3,5,4,1,5,4,4,6))

df2_final <- data.frame("group1"=c(373,357,382,411,310,315,330,385,367,396,402,348,354,343,392,395,392,401,376,448,341,373,369,304,298,332,366,287,334,222),                     "group2"=c(319,347,284,313,300,292,228,322,291,275,278,289,323,342,272,242,295,347,290,343,337,309,268,251,256,266,346,260,232,160),                        "group3"=c(165,154,161,152,164,152,156,150,137,170,147,210,235,190,176,175,191,186,209,157,210,199,162,149,162,165,174,171,178,126),                        "group4"=c(253,274,240,258,264,231,296,233,230,252,210,233,233,295,235,229,270,275,278,297,255,253,250,252,299,305,310,308,263,141))
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? Appreciate for any help. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could use either reticulate or jsonlite. I will use Jsonlite as below:

for `df1`:

```
df1_f <- jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub('"+','"',sprintf("[%s]", paste0(df1, collapse = ","))))

data.frame(Day = names(df1_f), `colnames<-`(t(df1_f), paste0("count",1:4)), row.names = NULL)

          Day count1 count2 count3 count4
1   Wednesday      4      6      5      3
2      Monday      5      5      5      5
3    Saturday      4      2      3      4
4    Thursday      4      6      8      1
5     Tuesday      5      0      4      5
6      Friday      1      2      3      4
7      Sunday      5      4      6      4
8 Missing day      2      1      4      6
```

for `df2` since the lists are not within the `{}` we will have to manually transform it to a dataframe:

```
df2_fin <- jsonlite::fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]",paste0(df2, collapse = ",")))
(df2_final <- setNames(data.frame(t(df2_fin)), paste0("group",1:4)))

   group1 group2 group3 group4
1     373    319    165    253
2     357    347    154    274
3     382    284    161    240
4     411    313    152    258
5     310    300    164    264
6     315    292    152    231
7     330    228    156    296
8     385    322    150    233
9     367    291    137    230
10    396    275    170    252
11    402    278    147    210
12    348    289    210    233
13    354    323    235    233
:
:
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for me. Could you suggest any other packages like jsonlite that could be used to resolve these kinds of data structure or any link to learn these packages?

Comment: @smk. You will first have to recognize the structure of your datase. Ie the first one looks like a list of dictionaries in python while the second looks like a list of lists. That’s why you can use the reticulate package. Also note that both looks like a JavaScript object ie (JSon) Hence we can use any Json library in R eg, RJson, jsonlite etc